# How to delete files of package when it's failed to install?

Tags: laravel

I failed to install `Voyager package` for some reasons,
But when i tried to run

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

or

```
php artisan migrate
```

I got this error

```
       Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 La table 'project.menu_items' n'existe pas (SQL: alter table `menu_items` add `route` varchar(191) null, add `parameters` text null)

  at C:\wamp\www\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 La table 'project.menu_items' n'existe pas")    C:\wamp\www\project\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:143
  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 La table 'project.menu_items' n'existe pas")
     C:\wamp\www\project\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:141
```

I think the project.menu_items belong to the voyager package
I tried to delete the package by running

```
composer remove vendor/the_package_name
php artisan cache:clear  
php artisan config:clear
```

with no result. Please help!

Comment: do as in documentation: https://voyager.readme.io/docs/installation  1. `composer require tcg/voyager`  2. `php artisan voyager:install`

Comment: the problem is not how to install the package but how to remove it definitely

Comment: it depends how deeply it ruins Your previous app structure, if it's just a fresh app so why not to create it from scratch again? if it was working app and then You've attached voyager and now You want to remove I hope You had tracked changes with GiT. Otherwise have to find changed files and etc and remove them manually or just talk with contributors about uninstall scenario